# Sort alphanumerically using spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, sorting, jpa

I have an application where I sort using one field, but the result is not the expected one. For example, the result for the query is:

- ABC-1, ABC-2, ABC-11, ABC-12

After the sorting, my result is:

- ABC-1, ABC-11, ABC-12 and ABC-2

But the result I am looking for is:

- ABC-1, ABC-2, ABC-11 and ABC-12

I have read some answer with no success.
I use PageRequest object where I define the pageIndex, pageSize and the Sort object

Comment: What Spring Data JPA is doing, is sorting the strings alphanumerically. But what you really want is something else than sorting alphanumerically: you want to sort the prefix alphanumerically, but the suffix numbers numerically. You'll need to add your own custom sort criteria do get what you want.

Comment: The problem is that the field does not have a fixed pattern. I used those string in order to explain the problem, but the lenght of the first part is not fixed. Event the first part of the string can contain some numeric values

Comment: DBs and most generic operations on strings just look at them as characters going through each one by one. What you want requires parsing sets of characters, looking beyond just the current one, so that A11B would be behind A1A. That could be quite expensive with moderate data sets. If you can't look at it as character data, you should break up the string values into different columns so that you can make better comparisons. Put ABC portion into its own column separate from the next part, so that each can be compared individually.

Answer (score 2):

`Sping data JPA` with JpaRespository provides sorting features based upon Database SQL capabilities, using `order by your_field ASC/DESC`. So `Spring data JPA` sorting feature is limited with what `SQL` ordering offers:
[For more details](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-sorting)

`SQL order by` sorts your data alphanumerically, so if you need to implement your custom sorting in the application level, buy implementing you custom comparator:
[Sorting data with custom comparator](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-comparator-how-to-sort-a-list)

Comment: So I would have to sort the data after getting it from the database, right? Is there no way to build the query properly to get the data already sorted the way I want?

Comment: @RamónParejoCuéllar you can customize the query by using the `@Query` annotation in your repository, [more info here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query). If you do it like that you'll have to find a way to express your sort criteria in SQL.